# Iterate over SAX

Tags: python, sax

I have an xml like this (just an example):

```
<xml>
  <page>
    <lol>
    </lol>
    <lel>
    </lel>
  </page>
  <page>
    <lol>
    </lol>
    <lel>
    </lel>
  </page>
  <page>
    <lol>
    </lol>
    <lel>
    </lel>
  </page>
</xml>
```

I need a way to do something like this:

```
#Sax code

for page in something:
  parse(page)
```

How i can do this with sax?

The xml file contains 30GB of data.

Comment: lxml uses trees, not SAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the sax parser in a thread. When it detects a full fage it pushes it to a queue. In your main thread, iterate over the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use SAX, use [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET

for event, elem in ET.iterparse("/path/to/your/file"):
    if elem.tag == 'page':
        # do your processing
        elem.clear()
```

The `elem.clear()` call is important, otherwise you will keep all the processed elements in memory and eventually consume all your RAM, too. The element objects are light-weight DOM-like objects, so they are quite easy to use, as compared to SAX.

If the individual `page` elements are too large already to fit your memory, you will have to revert to SAX, but I assume from your example that there are many small `page` elements rather than a few large ones.

Comment: If you have lots and lots of `page` elements this can still use up a lot of memory.  See http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm#incremental-parsing for a technique to deal with that case.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficent and pythonic way to do this with xml.sax is to use the **parser.feed()** method.

Example:

```
parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
parser.setContentHandler(YourContentHandler)

f = open('terribly_large.xml', 'r')
for line in f.xreadlines():
    parser.feed(line)
```

This ensures that you're both incrementally reading the file, and incrementally parsing it.

The resulting memory footprint should be minimal.

Answer (score -2):

use Dom instead of Sax , sax keep fire event when it occur interest stuff like start element or text , but if you want to iterate over the file use dom this [link](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) may help you .

UPDATE:

with 30GB you must use SAX

Comment: With 90 GiB of RAM, you should be on the safe side.

Comment: @Torsten Marek i post my answer before he edit the question :( !!